# Vertical Space after creating two mini pages in Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, wrap

[image: Example]

Want to make the spacing between the headers the same for the bottom one as it is the top. Issue originally came from not being able to warp the image.

Comment: does \vfill before and after \includegraphics help?

Comment: @marmot no it doesn't

Comment: can you make a mwe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution probably works if you add an empty line before the `\vspace` command. Since you didn't provide the code, I can't verify. Below is how I would do it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % I've never seen anyone using it
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Curve Offsetting}
  \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
      \emph{What is it?}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item A Computer Numerical Control (CNC) machine is a tool that
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
      \item A CNC evaluates all mathematics in a coordinate system.
      \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

  \bigskip  
  \emph{Why is it necessary?}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should simply continue the text in the left column.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Curve Offsetting}

\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
  \emph{What is it?}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item A Computer Numerical Control (CNC) machine is a tool that
        uses programmed controls to perform tasks such as milling,
        pressing, grinding and many other tasks.
  \item A CNC evaluates all mathematics in a coordinate system.
  \end{itemize}\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}

\emph{Why is it necessary?}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, restore the correct spacing after the `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Curve Offsetting}

\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
  \emph{What is it?}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item A Computer Numerical Control (CNC) machine is a tool that
        uses programmed controls to perform tasks such as milling,
        pressing, grinding and many other tasks.
  \item A CNC evaluates all mathematics in a coordinate system.
  \end{itemize}\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}

\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\prevdepth=\tpd
\vspace{\topsep}
\emph{Why is it necessary?}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\tpd` trick is necessary because of the `T`op alignment in the `columns` environment.

The misalignment is due to the `columns` environment, which is why I suggest to continue with the column.